# displaying issue in C

Tags: c

I was wondering if there is a way of displaying a message in C such as: "message": variable, and the variable modify itself. Something like when you load a program and you see:
Loading 23%..24% and so on. thanks a lot (by display a message I mean a simple printf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can acheive a rough aproximation of this on the command line by using carriage return ( Assuming your command line handles those properly ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int spin (void) {
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        printf("%d\r", i);
        sleep( 1 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: haha R very true -- I mean usleep there, have made it just sleep( 1 );

Answer (score 4):

You can use the carriage return (`\r`) instead of the line feed (`\n`) to go back to the beginning of the current line... the next `printf()` will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing backspaces `"\b"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep */

int main(void) {
  int k;

  printf("Percentage completed: ");

  for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
    printf("%3d%%", k);
    fflush(stdout);

    {  /* work */
      sleep(1);
    }

    printf("\b\b\b\b");
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  printf("100%%\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use `\r`...it's more reliable than `\b`, e.g. if the user accidentally types some characters.